# Javascript to move focus onkeyup getElementById Works getElementsByClassName does not

Tags: javascript, focus, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to move the focus from one input field to the next one once the key is pressed.
For some reason it works when I am using getElementById but when I am changing it to getElementByClassName it does not.

Works:

```
<input id="char1" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('char2').focus()" />
<input id="char2" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('char3').focus()" />
<input id="char3" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('char1').focus()" />
```

Does not work:

```
<input class="char1" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementsByClassName('char2').focus()" />
<input class="char2" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementsByClassName('char3').focus()" />
<input class="char3" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementsByClassName('char1').focus()" />
```

Comment: typo. it has to be plural - `Elements` not `Element`. Then again, `getElementsByClassName()` will return an array like object so you'll need to specify index.

Comment: Thanks, Changed it to getElementsByClassName(), but still not moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because classes are retrieved as arrays so you have to access it by index and also you did an error it's `document.getElementsByClassName` not `Element`.

```
<input class="char1" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementsByClassName('char2')[0].focus()" />
<input class="char2" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementsByClassName('char3')[0].focus()" />
<input class="char3" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeyup="document.getElementsByClassName('char1')[0].focus()" />
```